# typedef struct from C to Swift

Tags: ios, c, swift, bridging-header

I'm working on a Swift app that accesses a C library.

The .h file contains a typedef struct:

```
typedef struct _DATA_KEY_ * CURRENT_DATA_KEY;
```

And there a method in another class:

```
 -(int) initWithKey(CURRENT_DATA_KEY * key);
```

I need to create a CURRENT_DATA_KEY in my code. Not sure how I can achieve that in Swift.

There is some old Objective-C code that uses:

```
CURRENT_DATA_KEY key = NULL;
initWithKey(key)
```

I've tried:

```
let myKey = UnsafeMutablePointer<CURRENT_DATA_KEY>.allocate(capacity: 1)
```

But when I try to use it later as an argument in the function, I get the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_DATA_KEY_>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer(<OpaquePointer>)') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer(<_DATA_KEY_?>!)'
```

Which looks like the function is expecting an optional value?

I also tried:

```
let myKey: CURRENT_DATA_KEY? = nil
let myKey: CURRENT_DATA_KEY = NSNull()
```

But those get similar type errors.

How do I create: `UnsafeMutablePointer(<_DATA_KEY_?>!)`

Comment: Does `var myKey: CURRENT_DATA_KEY = nil` work?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a bit since I've done this but IIRC this:

```
typedef struct _DATA_KEY_ * CURRENT_DATA_KEY;
-(int) initWithKey(CURRENT_DATA_KEY * key);
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
-(int) initWithKey(struct _DATA_KEY_ ** key);
```

So if we look up [Interacting with C APIs: Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23) it falls under:

> `Type **`

Which becomes:

> `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Type>`

If you know the members of the C `struct` then you may be able to treat it like a Swift `struct` and use the synthesized `init` method. So if it is defined like this:

```
struct _DATA_KEY_ { 
  int foo
};
```

It becomes like this in Swift:

```
public struct _DATA_KEY_ { 
  var foo: Int
  init()
  init(foo: Int)
}
```

And you call the init method like:

```
// no parameter
let myKey = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<_DATA_KEY_>(&_DATA_KEY_())

// parameter
let myKey = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<_DATA_KEY_>(&_DATA_KEY_(foo: 12))
```

I have not tried this code but I've followed the advice in the Apple document before and it's worked out well.